# How to capture hidden values with Gravity Forms

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, multisite, plugin-gravity-forms

I will be using the following code from ActiveProspects and what it do is basically pass some hidden values (in this case basically a dynamic url) to the server along with the form fields which we need to capture and store in our DB. Now I am using Gravity Forms with my Wordpress site but I am unable to capture that data.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
      var field = 'xxTrustedFormCertUrl';
      var provideReferrer = false;
      var invertFieldSensitivity = false;
      var tf = document.createElement('script');
      tf.type = 'text/javascript'; tf.async = true;
      tf.src = 'http' + ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 's' : '') +
        '://api.trustedform.com/trustedform.js?provide_referrer=' + escape(provideReferrer) + '&field=' + escape(field) + '&l='+new Date().getTime()+Math.random() + '&invert_field_sensitivity=' + invertFieldSensitivity;
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(tf, s); }
  )();
</script>
<noscript>
    <img src="http://api.trustedform.com/ns.gif" />
</noscript>
```

The following image shows the hidden data and fields [image]

Now here's a gravity forms help page https://docs.gravityforms.com/using-dynamic-population/ which says how to pass dynamic data but I am not into php much so any help will be well appreciated. As per this help I have added the following code in my theme functions.php but I think its hard coded. So can anybody let me know how to capture this hidden field value and store it.

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_xxTrustedFormCertUrl', 'my_custom_population_function' );
function my_custom_population_function( $value ) {
    return 'Boom';
}
```

Comment: Does the script create the xxTrustedFormCertUrl input field or just populate one you've already added to the form? If it's populating one you should be able to get it to write the value straight into a Gravity Forms hidden field, which with have a name something like input_1. In which case you'd want PHP to find the name of the field and inject it into the script, not try and autopopulate the field from a non-Gravity input submitted with the form.

Comment: But if you did want to use the custom population function I guess you'd just read the value from $_POST.

Comment: The above javascript creates this xxTrustedFormCertUrl hidden field and its value now I just need to get it into any of the gravity form fields that a create. But it seems I have to write some php code in order to capture this value from this hidden field and save it against that gravity form filed. And the worst part is I am from marketing and know nothing about php.